# Working with multiple tables in Magento 2 Custom Module

Tags: magento2, database, magento-2.2.5

I am writing a videos module which I have a table called videos.

I would also like to use a table called techniques that I want to populate a drop-down box.

From what I have been googling there was an example that I think was from Magento 1 and an answer that said it takes 6 hours to do and you should have a professional do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated on how to use multiple tables in my module.

Comment: Are you want it for admin grid or frontside?

Comment: Can this help you? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7525/modify-core-tables-vs-custom-tables-and-joins?rq=1

Comment: Its admin grid.